# MSD Radix Sort implementation Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm

Trying to implement a MSD version of radix version in Swift

```
func sort(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int]{
    var arr = array
    let base = 10
    var digitPosition = 10
    while (digitPosition>0) {
        var buckets = [[Int]](repeating: [], count: base)
        for number in arr {
            let remainder = number / digitPosition
            let numberDigit = remainder % base // base is 10
            buckets[numberDigit].append(number)
        }
        digitPosition /= base
        arr = buckets.flatMap {$0}
    }
    return arr
}
```

The input to run the sort is:

```
sort([112,2,3,104,15])
```

The output of my buckets are these:

```
[[112, 2, 3, 104, 15], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[2, 3, 15], [112, 104], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[2, 3, 104], [15, 112], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [2, 112], [3], [104], [15], [], [], [], []]
```

These are not correct.

**1. How can I append preceding 0's to Integers in Swift**

**2. How can I remove single bucket Integers from subsequent executions?**

Comment: Integers don't have preceeding zeros. There is no such integer number.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to display an int with leading zeros:

```
let value = 3
print(String(format: "%03d", value))
```

Will display "003"

Not sure what you mean by "single bucket integers"